# Override IDE keyboard shortcuts at design-time

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to create some productivity tools for other developers that use the Borland Delphi 7.0 IDE, to create some complex forms, but I'm hitting a wall every time I want to add a new keyboard shortcut, as they are already in use by the IDE.

Is there a way to override some of these shortcuts so I can respond with my own custom behavior?

Elaborating on this question, I want to add that I want to change the shortcuts when I open some special form, not in the whole IDE.

Comment: For complex forms, I recommend [CnPack](http://cnpack.org) which gives you a myriad of smart tools. Or if the form is very complex, simply drop controls somewhere and put everything in place when initiating the form (by code). I often use this method to make "responsive" form design.

Comment: Installing a keyboard hook (via Windows API) might be an option. Possibly the only one, because I know of no other way.